# Is there any way to monitor port(which is already in use by another application) in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, monitoring

Is there any way that we can a particular port which is in use by another application on nodejs?

For example, I want to monitor port 4000 which is used by another application on my ubuntu system. I want to know which IP connections are established with port 4000. and It should be a realtime event-driven. like if any new IP connects with port 4000 then It logs data or any custom action that I can set.

Is it possible on NodeJS?

Comment: Maybe you can achieve this using https://github.com/mscdex/cap.

Comment: Did you find anything?